# ADODB CreateInstance returns ERROR_NO_TOKEN 1008

Tags: c++, adodb, windows-server

I am trying to access a SQL database on a Windows 2003 server (although I would be doing this on 2000 servers as well), but when I try to call `CreateInstance` with a _ConnectionPtr object, it fails with "ERROR_NO_TOKEN: 1008: An attempt was made to reference a token that does not exist."  The code could not be simpler:

```
hResult = m_lpADOConnect.CreateInstance("ADODB.Connection");
```

Is there some other initialization I need to do before making this call?  Thanks for all help and advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.  I was forgetting to call `CoInitialize(NULL);` beforehand.